# Is there any way to change access modifier of a java method on runtime?

Tags: java

How can I change the modifier to be private instead public at runtime?

```
public class modifiableClass {

    public modifiableClass(){   
    }


    /* This method, If i want to change the modifier to be private
     * at runtime.
     */
    public void exampleMethod() {
        //method body
    }

}
```

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: using reflection? just curious!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Making it accessible I understand, but the inverse...?

Comment: i want to write a method that controll some overriding methods at runtime

Comment: is there other way??

Comment: Even if it could be done, hiding a public method would violate the class’s contract and would violate object oriented design.  If you pass me a NumberFormat object, I am expecting it to have a public `parse(String)` method, no matter which concrete subclass it is.  A better option is to wrap the class in a different type which exposes only some of the wrapped class’s methods.

Comment: ok. Got another way. Thanks

Comment: `private` methods are invoked differently that non-`private` methods in the JVM, so even if you poked the relevant bits there would be problems.